# How to access a mysql database hosted on RDS with AWS Console Access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

This may be a dumb question. I have been given admin access to AWS (and no other credentials) there is already an RDS mysql database setup. how do I create my own access to login and export a mysql database, without effecting anyone else who may already have access?

I was creating the site from myself i'd create a mysql user and login with sequel pro

Thanks.

Comment: It is a normal database. Do whatever you normally do. Amazon RDS will create the initial 'master' user, but after that it has nothing to do with AWS.

Comment: Sorry i mean the database has already been setup by someone else and i don't have any login details for it except my AMI Amazon login... So the only way i know to access the data would be to reset the Master Password, login and create a mysql user for myself.. but i'd rather not reset the master password incase someone else is using it... and i think there is supposed to be a way i can do it, but i can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: There is no way to find out the master password from the RDS console. You would have to reset it, but as you point out, it might break access for someone else. Do you have access to any deployed code that is using this database that may have the database credentials set either within the code or as environment variables?

Comment: @littleforest no the code base using 'secrets', maybe what i'm looking for just doen't exist. When the development team handed the website over i asked for Database Credentials to access the database.  and they replied "Key can be created in AWS, you have AWS Admin access". and this has gone back a forwards a few time. So I was trying to figure out how to do that. if i have to i can reset the master password and deal with any issues.but i'd rather not the the guy who does't know how to access databased properly

Comment: @Keenly what framework is the underlying application built in? Rails, Node.js, etc.? While Adiii's solution is great if you just need to get a copy of the database data, it doesn't allow you to modify/access the live data of the application if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way to do that

- Take the snapshot of RDS
- Launch RDS instance from this snapshot
- Goto setting and modify the master password of newly created instance
- Export all database
- Shutdown the newly created instance

This is the way without affecting the existing user or without changing the master password of your existing RDS.

Comment: thanks that sounds like it might be the best answer. it's not what i was looking for. was expecting there to be some smart way to access databases using a 'key' file generated in the console or something, but if that's not a thing then i guess this is the right answer.